# calculating android device moving speed (Using accelerometer and gyroscope)

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I need to create an app that Calculates the device's velocity, with x/y/z speed.

My idea is using device's accelerometer and gyroscope,

like this [pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ad5Q.jpg)

I wanted to know that whether accelerometer and gyroscope right sensor choice for this ?
(in the pipeline).

What Rotation table should i use for this?

Comment: yes,you can use both of these,but prefer doing it with accelerometer because some devices dont have gyrosensor.

Comment: No, these are not suitable, as the error will quickly integrate beyond meaning.  This question has been asked here many times before.

Comment: I would suggest the same as Chris.